# AtomicInteger Class Inconsistency

Tags: java, oop

I am using a AtomicInteger class to increment the value of customerID and productID.
I dont have a database but I am using the serialization to store the state of the application and its a command based application. Everytime I add a customer or a product their costructor calls the IDGenerateor class that has AtomicInteger to create a ID.
But there is inconsistency, somtimes it increment the ID and sometimes not, Could anyone tell me whats wrong.

```
public final class IdGenerator implements Serializable
{
  private static AtomicInteger nextID = new AtomicInteger();

  public static int newID() 
  {
    return nextID.incrementAndGet();
  }
}



public Customer (String name, String email, String phone, Address address) 
{
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", ""); // drop all non-digit characters
    this.address = address;
    this.ID = IdGenerator.newID();
    this.facebook="";
    this.twitter="";
    this.deliveryInstructions="";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the constructor code that calls the IdGenerator class.

Comment: So you're saying that sometimes you end up with two `Customer` objects with the same ID? That sounds unlikely to me - can you create a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet thats right, Actually its a huge program so dont know how to short program demosntration. Is there any other way to share the code?

Comment: @Learner How do you create your Customer, what constructor you use, does this class have another constructors?  What is the actual ID that is the same?

Comment: @Learner: No, because I don't think you'll find that anyone wants to plough through your huge program. Instead, *you* should work on finding a way of demonstrating it with a short program. Take a copy of your code, then hack out large swathes of it until the program goes away - at which point you restore the last thing you removed, and remove something smaller instead, etc. But I very much doubt that the problem is within `AtomicInteger`. You understand that if you run your program a second time, you'll start off with a new counter, right? Might that be the problem?

Comment: (In other words, if you run the program once and create/save 5 customers, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, then run it again and it loads the existing 5, then creates a new one, that new one will have an ID of 0, because you've got a new `nextID` starting at 0.)